# AS3 - Error #1009 and cannot find cause of issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animate-cc

Using AS3 in Animate CC, I get this error:

> Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

I have read through all the work-through for this error On Stack Overflow but I still can't figure this one out.  Any help would be a blessing.

I have a navigation panel of 96 buttons I'm attempting that when user clicks a movie from the library appears. A couple problems, first the error 1009 and also secondly when a new MovieClip appears the current one needs to go away.

Label for one of the buttons

```
btn_SAFER_25_1Jan
```

Label for Movie clip Symbol property

```
mcSaf_Jan01_25
```

Label for Name of Movie Symbol Class

```
Saf_Jan01_25
```

Code below, each frame of timeline that suppose to load each movie has similar, this one is for Jan 1 25

```
stop();

var saf_Jan01_25:Saf_Jan01_25=new Saf_Jan01_25;
addChild(saf_Jan01_25);
addChildAt(saf_Jan01_25,0);
saf_Jan01_25.x=394;//sets the x position
saf_Jan01_25.x=344;//sets the y position

saf_Jan01_25.visible = true;
saf_Jan01_100.visible = false;
saf_Jan01_250.visible = false;
saf_Jan01_500.visible = false;
```

script below is on timeline of for each navigation button

```
btn_SAFER_25_1Jan.addEventListner(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseOverHandler2);
btn_SAFER_25_1Jan.enabled = true;

function fl_MouseOverHandler2(eventMouseEvent):void
{
{
gotoAndPlay(2);
}
trace("Click");
}

btn_SAFER_100_1Jan.addEventListner(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseOverHandler3);
btn_SAFER_100_1Jan.enabled = true;

function fl_MouseOverHandler3(eventMouseEvent):void
{
{
gotoAndPlay(3);
}
trace("Click");
}
```

Comment: File > Publish Settings > Permit Debugging then you will know the exact line that is erroneous. It's a good start rather then trying to figure it from an incomplete picture.

Comment: PS: If Adobe hasn't changed it, use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` as shortcut to debugger. Hopefully it will give you the line number where error occurred (listed at top-most above other issues or other line numbers). Also when you say _"`Saf_Jan01_25` is label for Name of Movie Symbol Class"_ do you mean like `Class` entry in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYCxq.jpg)? Does it work if using `= new Saf_Jan01_25();`?

Comment: @VC.One Syntax is correct even without (), I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your comments...
Yes to the Class question. I'll try using = new Saf_Jan01_25(); and let you know.  Again thank you for responding!!!

Comment: var saf_Jan01_25:Saf_Jan01_25=new Saf_Jan01_25;
       addChild(saf_Jan01_25);
       addChildAt(saf_Jan01_25,0);
       saf_Jan01_25.x=394;//sets the x position
       saf_Jan01_25.x=344;//sets the y position

Comment: I'm still getting the error.   What I'm tiring to accomplish is when the user clicks on one of the 96 buttons, the corresponding movie clip loads from the library to the stage. If there is already a movie clip on the stage playing, that movie clip will be removed and the corresponding movie clip to the button clicked will load and play.  I just can't figure how to code it. Please help!

Comment: Does this look correct?    
           btn_SAFER_25_1Jan .addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,    fl_MouseOverHandler2);
          function fl_MouseOverHandler2 (e:MouseEvent):void {
          var newSaf_Jan01_25:Saf_Jan01_25 = new Saf_Jan01_25();
          this.addChild(newSaf_Jan01_25);
          newSaf_Jan01_25.x = 394;//sets the x position
          newSaf_Jan01_25.y = 344;//sets the y position